# objective-c: How blocks are created on low-level and at what cost?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Could not find detailed description.

Is it an object or function?

Is it created in runtime on demand or at compile-time or at loading stage?

Where they are created: On heap or on stack?

What is the invocation procedure and order?

Comment: Your question is Ok but is not about a code issue rather it deals with the theory, well you can find all about this in the Clang website or you need to improve the question to receive a good answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it an object or function?

Both;   a block is effectively a captured bit of state that is also callable like a function.   The compiler colludes to make the *object* part of it mostly transparent (especially with ARC).

> Is it created in runtime on demand or at compile-time or at loading stage?

Runtime or compile-time, depending on the block.

A block that captures no state can be entirely created at compile-time.   A block that captures state that can only be known at runtime will be created at runtime.

> Where they are created: On heap or on stack?

Both;  really, stack, heap, or static RO mapped memory (i.e. a compile time block).

Blocks (that capture state) are generally created on the stack and then promoted to the heap on the first Block_copy() operation.

> What is the invocation procedure and order?

Unclear what you are asking here.   Blocks are invoked just like C functions where the first argument is always a reference to the block object, giving a hook to grab the captured state.